# Automatically Run macro when Excel document is opened from SharePoint

Tags: excel

Is there a way to allow an excel document to run a macro when a excel file is opened from SharePoint 2010?

I'm trying to embed a chart on a quick lookup excel doc from a list hosted in SharePoint but the field I am using to create the chart is not aggregating the numbers because Excel thinks it's just text.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a macro that already works when you open Excel outside of SharePoint?

Comment: @jpollar I actually don't have anything that works at this time.

Comment: You have to walk before you can fly. lol The best way to do this would be with a pivot table anyway. You know how to do those?

Comment: @jpollar I think I miss understood your question. This is already built out as a pivot table. Still only allows me to see true numbers if I click in the cell and hit enter to actually receive it from SharePoint as a int. From SharePoint the numbers in column C aren't truly numbers read by Excel until I click into the cell and hit enter. When the form goes and gets refreshed data it all reverts back to non numbers.